Congratulations, Quantitative Finance is graduated!
It's a big day, Quantitative Finance met our threshold for graduation-worthy sites a while back and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.
Graduation works in two phases. Well, usually. To expand what happens per the first phase of graduation: 

You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name. This is already active.
You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network. This is already active.
You will have an election in order to elect moderators from the community, for the community. Due to the holidays, we haven't had large enough blocks of time to hold elections, which has resulted in a bit of backlog in elections. Yours will be scheduled either late January or early February.
You will be able to select your own community ads. These cycle at the start of each year, however - as there's not much of a year left, we'll be waiting until the change of the year before that gets up.
For the second phase, the site will at a later date receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. This will be preceded by the designer pitching their ideas and soliciting feedback from the community.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Congratulations everyone, we finally made it!

A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from a few weeks ago: Custom Quantitative Finance design and logo - Information gathering :)

Update: Your new site design is live!

This is a great achievement and I would like to thank all the contributors and my fellow moderators for helping the site making it out of Beta.
I look forward to seeing it evolve in the next phase and hopefully become the most prominent online resource from our field.

+1 and a big thanks to you and to Bob Jensen !
